# How can I show my tif images clearly with pixmap using pyqt4

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4, qpixmap

Here in my program I am displaying my tif images in scrollarea but view part of the image is not clear I tried many ways still I am getting the same way. Can anyone please tell me how can I display my images clearly in scrollarea?

Given below is my code:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
class Settings(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None,username='',password='',user=''):
        super(Settings, self).__init__(parent)

        self.newwidget = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.mainLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.newwidget)

        self.scrollArea_right = QtGui.QScrollArea(widgetResizable=True)
        self.scrollArea_right.setWidget(self.newwidget)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.scrollArea_right)
        # self.centralWidget().setLayout(self.mainLayout)

        print self.scrollArea_right.viewport().width(),self.scrollArea_right.viewport().height()

        self.lb = QtGui.QLabel()
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.lb)
        myPixmap = QtGui.QPixmap("/home/cioc/Desktop/Sample/DIR001/SH000003.tif")
        myScaledPixmap = myPixmap.scaled(638,478, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
        self.lb.setPixmap(myScaledPixmap)
        self.lb.setScaledContents(True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Settings()
    # w.resize(500,500)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: As you're scaling the image for display, it will never be fully readable. Find out the size of the scrollarea and try a resize of the file in a graphics package (GIMP) or create a new one from the command line using ImageMagick. The results will give you some hint as to where things are going wrong. Make sure your resize does NOT interpolate - the image you provided looks like it wasn't

Comment: Try using `Qt::SmoothTransformation` as `transformMode` for `scaled()`.